# How can i refresh one specific hWnd window every X minutes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i'm doing is capturing a screenshot of windows in the background.
In a ListBox i have items of windows i'm taking screenshots.
The idea is that the windows are in the background so i don't need to move the windows to the foreground each time.

In form1 constructor:

```
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

Then in form1 i also have a RefreshWindowsList method:

```
private void RefreshWindowsList()
        {
            Graphics g;
            g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            buttonSnap.Enabled = true;
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
            for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
                if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
                {
                    listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < listBoxSnap.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
                int index = tt.LastIndexOf(",");
                myList[i] = tt.Substring(0, index);
            }
            textBoxIndex.Text = listBoxSnap.Items.Count.ToString();
            if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
            }
            listBoxSnap.Select();
        }
```

The problem is that if i will make a refresh if i will call this method every X seconds/minutes the ListBox will blink.
So i was wondering if there is a way to refresh only a specific window form the WindowSnap.GetAllWindows collection and not to refresh the ListBox.

So if i refresh the specific hWnd window and save the window image as screenshot on the hard disk i will not see any changes on the ListBox but i will have a collection of images saved on the hard disk.

The class WindowSnap is  a bit long so i will give a link for it i don't want to add it all here:

[WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/eWKiWCR3)

And it's using also the class WindowSnapCollection.cs

[WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/UcTqnPVr)

The idea again is somehow to refresh specific hWnd window frol the collection and to refresh the ListBox.

Comment: You did it was my mistake i didn't explain it right i checked it now again and the problem is not that the listBox flicker but the time it's taking to update the items with the for loop while it's doing the for loop the listBox is empty. It's not flickering but it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable flicker while clearing and reloading items of `ListBox`, you can use `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods of `ListBox` control, for example in a timer with interval 1000 I wrote this code and there was no flicker in `ListBox`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(i);   
    }
    this.listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Also you can put your new items in a list and then, add them using :

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(yourItemsList.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: I think it was my mistake the problem is not that the listBox is flickering it does and i'm using now your solution. But the main problem is the time it's taking each time to make the refresh since there a for and i'm adding like 33 or more windows to the listBox and it's taking like 4-5 seconds and in this time the listBox is empty. So maybe there is a faster way to update the listBox ? Or maybe while it's updating to show something else maybe to keep showing the last items and update them in real time ?

Comment: @BenShabatShmuel If you use `BeginUpdate` first  and then `Items.Clear()`, the list will not show empty. Not related to delay.

Comment: @BenShabatShmuel Another thing you can consider, is you can use listBox1.Items.AddRange(), this way you can first put your new items in an array, then beginupdate, then clear, then addrange and at last end update.

Comment: You right the problem is not with adding to the listBox and i'm using AddRange the problem is with the classes i added the links of them in my question. In form1 this line: this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); the GetAllWindows make the delay the WindowSnap using also the WindowCollectionSnap class and there i saw it's adding in some places items.

Comment: @BenShabatShmuel I think with any delay, you can render the ListBox flicker free using this asnwer :) Hope you find the answer helpful:)

Comment: @BenShabatShmuel if you have any other problem like freezing UI, its better to ask a new question about it:)